# AngularJS 2 router not reloading proper component on navigation. only changing url

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services

I have a service which is subscribed to router events as follows:

```
this.router.events.filter(e => e instanceof RoutesRecognized)
.subscribe(event => {
    if(event.urlAfterRedirects !== "/my/other/page") {
        this.router.navigate(['/my/other/page']);
    }
});
```

then when i from my page redirect to a page,
I see the events :

```
NavigationStart ("/my/first/page")
RoutesRecognized ("/my/first/page")
NavigationCancelled
NavigationStart ("/my/other/page")
RoutesRecognized ("/my/other/page")
NavigationEnd ("/my/other/page")
```

and on my browser the url changes to `/my/other/page`  however the page content is not updated and there are no errors

What can be wrong please?

Comment: and when you manually hit URL it is fine?

Comment: You might need to show your route configuration for path `/my/other/page`

Comment: When I hit the url manually it still goes to /my/first/page

Comment: I meant when you dont have your above conditions and you enter /my/other/page, it is fine ?

Comment: no it is not. If i go to on the browser directly to /my/other/age it still shows /my/first/page I think its something in the route config at this point. looking into it a second